Expo iOS standalone build can't load yml file assets
I have an Expo iOS/Android app with many yml file assets.
The app works fine using ExpoGo and Android build.
However, whenever I try to build iOS standalone builds using eas build I always end up with the following error
Error: Calling the 'readAsStringAsync' function has failed\n\U2192 Caused by: File '/Users/johnDoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B463AF76-44EB-4DEF-9DB8-45BCA9B52BC1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE917BA8-E697-4645-A5BA-4C113E222627/Example.app/assets/assets/index.yml' is not readable

Fonts and images load fine though.

metro.config.js

const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config')

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)
config.resolver.assetExts.push('yml')

module.exports = config


Turns out Expo supports yml files by default. Re-adding the yml format to assetExts breaks the build for some reason.
